# jquery binding click event to multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 3 buttons b1, b2, b3. How to bind click on 3 buttons.
    Var b1 = $("#b1");
    Var b2 = $("#b2");

```
$(b1,b2).bind("click", function(){});
```

jsfiddle.net/Xqpaq/

Comment: Your code is incorrect, you cannot use a jQuery selector on a comma separated jQuery selections. If you want to do this, use an array notation like: $([b1, b2])

Comment: I want to use var objects only... selectors are to be of var type only

Comment: You could also just state: var b1 = "b1", b2 = "b2"; and then use $(b1,b2).bind()...

Comment: Hi kevin.. $(b1,b2) or $([b1],[b2]) is not working

Comment: My bad, use: var b1 = "#b1", b2 = "#b2";

Comment: Pls see the fiddle demo

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
b1.add(b2).add(b3).click(function(){
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ehgMa/1/)

or use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#b1, #b2, #b3').click(function(){
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ehgMa/2/)

Answer (score 16):

I would highly suggest making the button click function a separate function and then bind each button to it

http://jsfiddle.net/Xqpaq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

     var b1 = $("#btn1");
     var b2 = $("#btn2");
     var b3 = $("#btn3");

    var btnClick = function(e){
        alert("Button: "+e.currentTarget.id);
    }

    b1.on('click', btnClick);
    b2.on('click', btnClick);
    b3.on('click', btnClick);

});
```

The alternative is to use `classes` instead of `ids`. Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xqpaq/2/

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn-click-action" value="submit"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn-click-action" value="submit2"/>
<input type="button" id="btn3" class="btn-click-action" value="submit3"/>
```

Then JS:

```
var btnClassClick = function(e){
    alert("Button clicked from class: "+e.currentTarget.id);
}

$('.btn-click-action').on('click', btnClassClick);
```

Comment: While Arun's answer works, using the class instead of ids what the best answer for my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

wrap them in a div then target the div for all the button elements.

```
<div id="button-nav">
    <button class="button" type="button">button 1</button>
    <button class="button" type="button">button 2</button>
    <button class="button" type="button">button 3</button>
</div>
```

the js:

```
$('#button-nav').on('click','button', function (evt) {
   //-- do stuff
});
```

[JS Fiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/simondavies/qdQgd/)

Answer (score 7):

Giving jQuery an array will combine each item into a bigger jQuery object, thus you can bind your events in one shot.

**Assume b1 and b2 is DOM element, not jQuery object.**

```
$([b1, b2]).click(function (evt) { 
     // your code goes here 
});
```

JSFiddler at http://jsfiddle.net/XF3Vv/1/.

Comment: Could someone post a fiddle to this? I can't get it to work, but it seems really cool

Comment: My bad, b1 and b2 should be DOM elements, not jQuery objects. I thought jQuery object should usually prefixed with $.

Answer (score 5):

in your case:

just simply do like this below:

```
cj('#b1, #b2').click(function(){

        alert('you clicked either button 1 or button 2');

});
```

typical example:
do some thing like this for different elements, if you click on any of these elements then this click
event will be triggered

```
cj('#_qf_Contact_upload_view-top, #_qf_Contact_upload_new-top, ,#_qf_Contact_upload_view-bottom, #_qf_Contact_upload_new-bottom').click(function(){
    console.log(cj('#first_name').val());
    if(cj('#first_name').val() == '' || cj('#first_name').val().length == 0)
     {
        alert('First Name is a required field, cannot be empty');
        return false;
    }
});
```

hope it helps some one :)